# How can i validate two hours with Yup?

Tags: javascript, validation, react-native, formik, yup

I have a validation schema for my Formik Form on React Native using `Yup`. There are two fields (`start_time` and `end_time`) and i want to compare if `start_time` is after `end_time` and thrown a message to user.

I read about [`mixed.when`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema) and tried to figure out a solution with that, but i'm blocked with it.

```js
const isSameOrAfterTime = (startTime, endTime) =>
  moment(startTime, HOUR_MINUTE_SECONDS_MASK).isSameOrAfter(endTime);

// example - data
// start_time: 08:00:25
// end_time: 10:23:42
```

```js
start_time: Yup.string().when(['start_time', 'end_time'], {
    is: (startTime, endTime) => isSameOrAfterTime(startTime, endTime),
    then: Yup.string() // ???
    otherwise: // ????
  }),
```

I want to thrown a message when the start_time is after end_time

[image: Edit rough-currying-t9n88]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `yup.test` instead.

https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema

```
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  // (end_time, screma, self)
  start_time: Yup.string()
  .test(
    'not empty',
    'Start time cant be empty',
    function(value) {
      return !!value;
    }
  )
  .test(
    "start_time_test",
    "Start time must be before end time",
    function(value) {
      const { end_time } = this.parent;
      return isSameOrBefore(value, end_time);
    }
  ),
  end_time: Yup.string()
});
```

```
const isSameOrBefore = (startTime, endTime) => {
  return moment(startTime, 'HH:mm').isSameOrBefore(moment(endTime, 'HH:mm'));
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-johnson-vdueg

Comment: eslint throws this error `Stateless functional components should not use 'this'` on line `const { end_time } = this.parent;` . Any recommendations to fix or should I just ignore?

Comment: Not sure, it seems it's getting confused and ESLINT thinks the function is a Component? Bizarre. Try naming the function and placing it else where? Or disable eslint for that line.